# Perl passing argument into eval

Tags: perl, arguments, eval

I'm facing an issue using eval function.

Indeed I have some function name inside a SQL database, my goal is to execute those functions within perl (after retrieve in SQL).

Here is what I'm doing, considering that $RssSource->{$k}{Proceed} contains "&test" as a string retrieved from SQL:

```
my $str2 = "ABCD";
eval "$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}";warn if $@;

sub test
{
   my $arg = shift;

   print "fct TEST -> ", $row, "\n";
}
```

This is working correctly and display:

```
fct TEST ->
```

However I would like to be able to pass $str2 as an argument to $RssSource->{$k}{Proceed} but I don't know how, every syntax I tried return an error:

```
eval "$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}$str2"
eval "$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}($str2)"
eval "$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}"$str2
eval "$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}"($str2)
```

May someone tell me how to properly pass an argument to the evaluated function?

Thanks a lot for your help

Regards.

Florent

Comment: Did you mean `$arg` instead of `$row`, or the other way around?

Comment: Yes you are right, I have rewritten my code before posting to strictly focus on my issue and didn't change the variable name properly in the test function, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}` always contain `name` or `&name`, otherwise what you are asking doesn't make much sense.

```
my $func_name = $RssSource->{$k}{Proceed};
$func_name =~ s/&//;
my $func_ref = \&$func_name;    # Works with strict on!
$func_ref->(@args);
```

If you want to add some error checking, the following will check if the sub can be called:

```
defined(&$func_ref)
```

Comment: Isn't line 3 just taking a reference to a sub called literally 'func_name'?

Comment: @Dondi Michael Stroma, oops, yeah! fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ikegami, looks to be the best way and thank you for your comment concernning error checking !

Answer (score 3):

If the string you are `eval`ing always is a sub invocation, you can construct the eval string in one of these ways:

```
$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed} . '($str2)'
```

(most general), or

```
$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed} . "(\"$str2\")"
```

(inelegant)

Here are the problems your solutions ran into:

`eval "$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}$str2"` evaluates to `eval "&testABCD"`. This sub doesn't exist.

`eval "$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}($str2)"` evaluates to `"&test(ABCD)"`. Bareword not allowed.

`eval "$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}"$str2` A string has to be followed by some sort of operator, not another variable.

`eval "$RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}"($str2)` You are trying to call a string as a function. This is not supported in Perl.

Comment: Thanks for the analyse and your answer Amon, this is really helpfull to understand what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the data in your database to contain just a function name, that is, `test` rather than `&test`, you can call a function by a symbolic reference, rather than using eval:

```
$fn="test";
&{$fn}("argument")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot EVil Otto, your are right the eval function is not the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You do not need eval if, as you say, your database just contains function names. You can use them as symbolic references (but please remove the &). The modern way to do it would not be using the & to dereference it but to use the arrow operator:

```
{
    no strict 'refs'; # hopefully you have strict on already...
    $RssSource->{$k}{Proceed}->($str2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dondi, I have to admit that at first read I prefer Ikegami's answer which is compatible with strict ref. May you tell me why you said this is the modern way to achieve this?

Comment: @ehretf ikegami's answer is fine, he does in fact use the arrow operator in the end. I added my own answer because his originally had a mistake in it. Now that it's fixed, I will give it an upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to ikegami's answer, using the `can` method, which is more my taste. TIMTOWTDI.

```
my $func_name = $RssSource->{$k}{Proceed};
$func_name =~ s/&//;
my $func_ref = __PACKAGE__->can($func_name)
  or die "No function named $func_name";
$func_ref->(@args);
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, the can method look interesting !